# angular: how to avoid state sharing

Tags: angular

I am exploring angular, and just got into an issue.

I have made a component representing a dialog, and has a template(html), a css and ts file.

This component(dialog) comes up when an item in a list is clicked.User can click on different items in list which would make look and content of the dialog vary. Based on several variables defined in ts file, I hide/unhide ui elements in dialog.

I was under impression that when an item in list is clicked, the dialog which comes up has a different component instance. And hence state segregation is maintained.

But on testing I found that in we have only one instance of component. This is causing interference in look of the dialog as user clicks on different items in list.

How can this be avoided?

Comment: Could you share your code? It's very hard to identify the issue just by this description.

Comment: The description alone doesn't make it very apparent on how you're using the component. Indeed, as @IoannisStefanou noted, this really requires a minimal setup

Answer (score 0):

There isn't only one instance of a component. It's somethings else that's causing this behavior.
You can verify that by using the following component (a simple button with a counter):

custom-button.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "custom-button",
  templateUrl: "custom-button.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["custom-button.component.scss"]
})
export class CustomButtonComponent {
  points = 1;

  constructor() {}

  plus1() {
    this.points++;
  }
}
```

custom-button.component.html

```html
<div>
  <button (click)="plus1()">{{ points }}</button>
</div>
```

Import the component like this:
app.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { CustomButtonComponent } from "./button/custom-button.component"; // import it here
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, CustomButtonComponent], // declare it here
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then finally add the following in app.componenet.html:

```html
<custom-button></custom-button>
  <custom-button></custom-button>
```

You will see by clicking on each button that they increase by one separately. We will need to see your code to help you finding the cause

Comment: That's actually not correct. Each time a component is applied, it creates an instance of itself. That's why we have services and Input and Output to interact with the components.